# What is the proper configuration for Quadro RTX3000 to run tensorflow with GPU?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

My laptop System is Win10, with GPU NVIDIA Quadro RTX3000.
While trying to set up the TensorFlow with GPU, it always can't recognize my GPU.
What is the proper configuration for CUDA/CUDNN/Tensorflow etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I did suffer a while before making it works.
Here is my configuration:

- Win10
- RTX 3000
- Nvidia driver version 456.71
- cuda_11.0.3_451.82_win10  (can't works with 11.1 version, not sure why)
- cudnn -v8.0.4.30
- Python 3.8.7
- Tensorflow 2.5.0-dev20210106  (2.4 don't support cuda 11.x)

Comment: With above configuration, the GPU device can be recognized by TensorFlow. Unfortunately, there are still having errors while running the TensorFlow demo code (sorry forget to record it down), and can't figure a way to make it work. I gave up the GPU version and move back to the CPU ones. Anyone has the working RTX3000 environment, pls. kindly share your configuration, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, You could have simply installed Anaconda on windows and run the command `conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu` which would install the required CUDA, Tensorflow, CUDNN (correct versions) while forming a separate environment to effortlessly install Tensorflow.

It's the easiest solution, one that works out-of-the box and automates all the tasks.

Comment: I did try this, still fail to get the correct configuration for my environment. But i believe this should be the right way for most others.